# Glassfish EAR deployment time exception

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am trying to deploy to EAR to Glassfish which uses JSF and WAR file inside the EAR have `faces-config.xml` ie under WEB-INF. But when I try to deploy to Glassfish server I am getting below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Unable to parse document 'jndi:/server/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml': null
```

I am not sure what is the problem, Eclipse didn't gave me any error while writing faces-config.xml, but Glassfish is giving above error. And yes, I have faces-config.xml inside WEB-INF folder.

Here is the sample of `faces-config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<!-- there are other elements here -->
</faces-config>
```

I cannot post whole xml file since it is huge and FYI, I am trying to deploy Duke's book store Oracle sample Java EE app, but I am stuck with this error. I tried searching in  Google, but didn't get any useful result. Can you kindly help me? If needed I can provide more information.

My faces-config.xml can be found here: http://temp-share.com/show/gFHKBRxsY

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something wrong in your `faces-config.xml`. 
Maybe you are missing a `>` or something similar. 
You'll have to post or link to the file to provide more information.

**Update:**

As you have linked to your actual faces-config.xml I can see that the beginning of the file is not equal with the one you've posted.

In your file you have:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

The error is in the second line...the XML namespace is wrong.

You have to change it to:

```
<?xml   version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
```

Actually the same as you've posted in your question :)

Comment: No, it doesn't work, even now I am getting same error in Glassfish.

Comment: I am using JSF 2.2 and I have the same error. If I use the 2.0 old header I can deploy it.